# Problem with a Java program that counts number of non self-intersecting paths between upper left to bottom right of a square array

Tags: java, arrays

It is well known that when one is allowed only to move right and down, the number of paths between the upper left cell to the bottom right cell of a rectanglular grid with side lengths n,m is the binomial coefficient n+m on n. I tried to think, at first in a mathematical manner, about the number of such paths when one is also allowed to move left and up; obviously the only way to give meaningful answer to such a question is to count non self-intersecting paths that do not go outside the rectangle (without those restrictions, the number of paths is infinite)

Since I had no idea how to count the number of such paths combinatorially, I wrote a java program that counts such paths and prints the paths, which I restricted to square arrays. However, already in an array of size 3x3, the program prints only 9 paths, while checking the number of such paths manually gave 12 paths. Here is the program:

```java
public class pathCalculator {

    public static int pathsCalculator(boolean[][] arr) {

        return pathsCalculator(arr, 0, 0, "");
    }

    public static int pathsCalculator(boolean[][] arr, int i, int j, String s) {
        if (i < 0 || i > arr.length - 1 || j < 0 || j > arr[0].length - 1) {
            return 0;

        } else if (arr[i][j] == false) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (i == arr.length - 1 && j == arr[0].length - 1) {
            s = s + "[" + (arr.length - 1) + "," + (arr.length - 1) + "]";
            System.out.println(s);
            return 1;
        } else {
            arr[i][j] = false;
            s = s + "[" + i + "," + j + "]";
            boolean[][] arr1 = new boolean[arr.length][arr.length];
            for (int n = 0; n <= arr.length - 1; n++) {
                for (int m = 0; m <= arr.length - 1; m++) {
                    arr1[n][m] = arr[n][m];

                }
            }
            return pathsCalculator(arr1, i + 1, j, s) + pathsCalculator(arr1, i - 1, j, s) + pathsCalculator(arr1, i, j + 1, s) + pathsCalculator(arr1, i, j - 1, s);

        }

    }

}
```

The boolean array that is checked is initialized in the main program to be a square of "true"'s.

The main ideas of the program are therefore:

- **Recursion** - each time the method calls to four variations of itself, which correspond to the four possibilies of: moving down,up,right and left.
- **Flagging forbidden cells** - each time the path approaches a given cell, the program changes the cell's boolean value from true to false. The second if condition causes the program to return 0 in case we arrived at a forbidden cell (this indicates the path is self-intersecting).
- **Creating copies of the original boolean array** - to prevent the different paths from interacting with each other on the same board, in each recursive step the previous boolean array values are copied into a new array.

So what is the problem with what I wrote? why it counts only a part of the total number of paths?

Comment: What are the intended precondition and postcondition of pathsCalculator()? What is the visual meaning of the parameters?

Comment: @Sam Ginrich - int i is the row, int j is the column, and String s is an auxillary mean used in order to print the path. Will it help if I will change the names of the variables to more meaningful names? I forgot to do it...

Comment: The stopping condition is when: 1. path exits the square (in this case it returns 0). 2. path arrives at a forbidden cell (in this case it returns 0). 3. path approaches the bottom right cell of the array (in this case it returns 1).

Comment: Excellent!  May be you could add a runnable main function with useful parameters. DoxyGen has good patterns to document functions.

Comment: Sorry if I dont understand (I'm new to stackoverflow), but what do you mean by "adding a runnable main function with useful parameters"? I've already checked the program in a main function on 3x3 and 4x4 arrays, and in the 3x3 case it didn't print all paths...

Comment: Recursion is better understood with an entry point. That would be a runnable program with example parameters.

Comment: @Sam Ginrich - is this what you meant? I added the main program I used and its output.

Comment: Great! Now, it's a traceable question.

Answer (score 1):

A minor change in the program, but of critical importance, enables the program to return the correct number of non self-intersecting paths bewteen the upper left cell to bottom right cell. In the coping part of the code, just before the recursive call, one should initialize 4 arrays instead of one, each of which is an identical copy of the previous array, and then let each of the four calls of pathscalculator method continue with a different copy of the array.

Here is the corrected version of the program:

```
public class pathCalculator{

public static int pathsCalculator(boolean[][] arr)
{

    return pathsCalculator(arr,0,0,"");    
}

public static int pathsCalculator(boolean [][] arr, int i, int j,String s)
{
    if(i<0||i>arr.length-1||j<0||j>arr[0].length-1)
    {
        return 0;    

    }
    else if(arr[i][j]==false)
    {
        return 0;    
    }
    if(i==arr.length-1&&j==arr[0].length-1) 
    {
        s = s+"["+(arr.length-1)+","+(arr.length-1)+"]";
        System.out.println(s);
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        arr[i][j]=false;
        s = s+"["+i+","+j+"]";
        boolean[][] arr1 = new boolean[arr.length][arr.length];
        boolean[][] arr2 = new boolean[arr.length][arr.length];
        boolean[][] arr3 = new boolean[arr.length][arr.length];
        boolean[][] arr4 = new boolean[arr.length][arr.length];
        for(int n=0;n<=arr.length-1;n++){
            for(int m=0;m<=arr.length-1;m++){
                arr1[n][m]=arr[n][m];
                arr2[n][m]=arr[n][m];
                arr3[n][m]=arr[n][m];
                arr4[n][m]=arr[n][m];

            }
        }
        return pathsCalculator(arr1,i+1,j,s)+pathsCalculator(arr2,i-1,j,s)+pathsCalculator(arr3,i,j+1,s)+pathsCalculator(arr4,i,j-1,s);

    }

}

}
```

Here is the main function:

```
public class pathCalculatorTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean[][] arr ={{true,true,true},{true,true,true}
                     ,{true,true,true}};
    System.out.println(pathCalculator.pathsCalculator(arr));

}

}
```

And this is the output:

[0,0][1,0][2,0][2,1][1,1][0,1][0,2][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][1,0][2,0][2,1][1,1][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][1,0][2,0][2,1][2,2]

[0,0][1,0][1,1][2,1][2,2]

[0,0][1,0][1,1][0,1][0,2][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][1,0][1,1][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][1,1][2,1][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][1,1][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][1,1][1,0][2,0][2,1][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][0,2][1,2][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][0,2][1,2][1,1][2,1][2,2]

[0,0][0,1][0,2][1,2][1,1][1,0][2,0][2,1][2,2]

12

It returns the correct number of paths for 3x3 square, but since I don't have full understanding why it was nessecary to initialize 4 arrays insted of one, I'm not sure it works well for larger arrays. By the way, the function f(n) where n is the length size of the square and f is the number of paths, appears to grow amazingly fast - for 4x4 squares the number of paths that the program returned is 184, and for 5x5 squares the number is 8512.